# Using selenium-webdriver to connect to meteor running on localhost times out in gitlab-runner

Tags: selenium, meteor, gitlab

We are currently running integration tests for our app using meteor through gitlab cicd. After bootstrapping, we launch meteor through

```
METEOR_LOCAL_DIR=.meteor/test meteor --once --settings ./private/settings/testing/acceptance_test/settings.json --port 5000
```

And run the following javascript after launch:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')

function testInIE11() {
    // Input capabilities
    const capabilities = {
        name: process.env.LT_TEST_NAME,
        platform: 'windows 10',
        browserName: 'Internet Explorer',
        browser_version: '11.0',
        'ie.compatibility': 11001,
        resolution: '1024x768',
        build: 'IE 11 regression test',
        tunnel: true,
        tunnelName: process.env.LT_TUNNEL_NAME
    }

    const grid_host = 'hub.lambdatest.com/wd/hub'
    const grid_url = `https://${process.env.LT_USERNAME}:${process.env.LT_ACCESS_KEY}@${grid_host}`
    console.log("Building driver....")
    const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .usingServer(grid_url)
        .withCapabilities(capabilities)
        .build()
    console.log("Driver built completed")


    driver
        .get('localhost:5000')
        .then(() => console.log("Sleeping..."))
        .then(() => driver.sleep(10000))
        .then(() => console.log("Finding email"))
        .then(() => driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('email')))
        .then(() => driver.quit())
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
            return driver.quit().then(() => process.exit(1))
        })
}

testInIE11()
```

However, about 50/50 the test stalls at driver.get('localhost:5000') and times out after an hour. these are the last log lines:

```
=> Started your app.
=> App running at: http://localhost:5000/
> a@2.0.0 test:ie11 /builds/ah/a-monorepo/packages/ah
> node tests/ie11.spec.js
Building driver....
Driver built completed
```

Anyone who encountered something similar? I cannot find any related issues...